# Tour of Heroes tutorial error 404 with "angular-in-memory-web-api"

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, vscode-devcontainer, angular-in-memory-web-api, angular-tour-of-heroes

I followed the [angular toh tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#get-heroes-with-httpclient) (literally copy pasted) and i'm now on part 6 at the step : 
Refresh the browser. The hero data should successfully load from the mock server.

However it doesn't load and i don't get any error when i run "ng serve"

But in inspect tool on browser i get the error : 
 `"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot GET /api/heroes</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"` 
with the message : 
**"Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/heroes: 404 Not Found"**

**i'm running my code in a vscode devcontainer** but i don't feel like it might be issue since port 4200 of container is bind to port 4200 of my computer and every content not linked to the db appear on the screen

some of my code
app.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService } from './in-memory-data.service';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail/hero-detail.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    MessagesComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    // The HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule module intercepts HTTP requests
    // and returns simulated server responses.
    // Remove it when a real server is ready to receive requests.
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
      InMemoryDataService, { dataEncapsulation: false }
    )
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

in-memory-data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { Hero } from './hero';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    const heroes = [
      { id: 12, name: 'Dr. Nice' },
      { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
      { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
      { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
      { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
      { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
      { id: 18, name: 'Dr. IQ' },
      { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
      { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
    ];
    return {heroes};
  }

  // Overrides the genId method to ensure that a hero always has an id.
  // If the heroes array is empty,
  // the method below returns the initial number (11).
  // if the heroes array is not empty, the method below returns the highest
  // hero id + 1.
  genId(heroes: Hero[]): number {
    return heroes.length > 0 ? Math.max(...heroes.map(hero => hero.id)) + 1 : 11;
  }
}
```

hero.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
import {MessageService} from './message.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {
  private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';  // URL to web api

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private messageService: MessageService) { }

  /** GET heroes from the server */
  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
  }

  getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
    // For now, assume that a hero with the specified `id` always exists.
    // Error handling will be added in the next step of the tutorial.
    const hero = HEROES.find(h => h.id === id)!;
    this.messageService.add(`HeroService: fetched hero id=${id}`);
    return of(hero);
  }

  /** Log a HeroService message with the MessageService */
  private log(message: string) {
    this.messageService.add(`HeroService: ${message}`);
  }
}
```

I saw on [www.github.com/angular/angular-in-memory-web-api](http://www.github.com/angular/angular-in-memory-web-api) that their version doesn't work anymore but the package on npm that i use is 2 month old and come from [www.github.com/angular/angular](http://www.github.com/angular/angular)

I'm lost and asking you for clues

Answer (score 1):

I just learnt `Nodejs` and `Angular` and had the similar problem too.
I have solved the problem this way. I just realised that, I have installed the `angular-in-memory-web-api` outside my project folder.
Then I tried installing it in my project folder with `--force` option (it succeed with some warnings) then it works fine.